# Is there a better way to run mysql update leftjoin

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to use a mysql command to update my table:

```
Update TableA left join
       TableB  -- I am guessing this belongs here
       on TableA.Key=TableB.key
    set TableA.column1=TableB.column1
    where TableA.Column2='XXX';*
```

what I want is update the records that both match Key condition and where clause while this code made other records only meet where clause: TableA.Column2='XXX' also change

As far as i know, using right join or inner join could also solve the problem, how ever, compared with left join, they take more time.

is there a way to improve this command;

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the query that you want:

```
update TableA a join
       TableB b
       on a.Key = b.key
    set a.column1 = b.column1
    where a.Column2 = 'XXX';
```

For this query, you want two indexes:  `TableA(Column2, key)` and `TableB(key)`.  These indexes should speed the query.

Comment: Is there a reason for an anonymous downvote on what looks like a correct answer?

Comment: thanks for answering，i ve tried it，however it takes more time than I expected，so I tend to use right join

Comment: @TaroNikkei . . . Even with the indexes?